# PHP: Get next value of an array until the foreach loop ends

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to get the $current_account in a foreach loop until the fooreach loops ends. I am using the next function which gives me the next element in an array until it reaches the end. How can I make it go to the first element in the array once it reached the end of the array?

```
$search_tags = array(
    "happy",
    "summer",
    "beach",
    "glasses",
    "umbrella",
    "funny",
    "people",
    "music",
    "rap"
);

$accounts = array(
    "account A",
    "account B",
    "account C"
);

foreach ($search_tags as $tag) {
    $current_account = current($accounts);
    print_r($current_account."\n");

};
```

So in this case the result should be like this:

Account B
Account C
Account A
Account B
Account C
Account A
Account B
Account C
Account A

But I am getting the following:

Account B
Account C

Comment: You need to reset $accounts when you reach the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `InfiniteIterator`

```
$accounts = new InfiniteIterator(new ArrayIterator($accounts));
$accounts->rewind();

foreach($search_tags as $tag) {
    echo ucfirst($accounts->current()), PHP_EOL;
    $accounts->next();
}
```

[See Live Demo](http://eval.in/32581)

Comment: Sweet solution - now I've found a good use for InfiniteIterator

Comment: @DaniilVnoutchkov That's what you asked for in your question.

Comment: In defence: your original question indicated that it should start at Account B

Comment: Why does it start at "AccountB" and not "AccountA"? I can't see why it does that.

Comment: Yeah I am sorry, I edited my question. I would like to start at the first value of an array and go to the next one.

Comment: @vascowhite because `rewind` was not called . if it was passed to foreach directly `rewind` would have been called

Comment: @Baba OK, thanks for the answer. I'm still not sure, but I'll go do some reading :)

Answer (score 0):

There are other simple ways of doing this, such as by accessing the accounts elements by index depending on the current index, as below;

```
foreach ($search_tags as $index => $tags) {
    print_r($accounts[$index % count($accounts)] . "\n");
}
```

Which outputs;

```
account A
account B
account C
account A
account B
account C
account A
account B
account C
```